# Is it possible to duplicate a shape via a transform (or something else)

Tags: wpf, xaml

I'm trying to create a pause style button in XAML. To create the standard two side-by-side bars, it seems like I should be able to draw a single rectangle, and the apply some sort of transformation to duplicate it and offset the duplicated rectangle, but I've no idea where to begin. Creating two rectangles doesn't seem like the right approach to me, but I don't really know enough about XAML to know for sure

Comment: Have a look at: [this article](http://weblogs.asp.net/gavinleader/silverlight-2-creating-a-play-pause-button-using-a-controltemplate). Other than that, I don't see any issue with creating two rectangles...

Comment: Yeah, I saw that article... he goes with two rectangles. I guess it's not that big of a deal, I just wanted to make sure I wasn't missing something obvious. Thanks!

Comment: 2 rectanges in a stackpanel, cant get much simpler than that, or just use `Webdings` font on the button and use the pause symbol from that

Comment: Convert two rectangles to path and then combine them into one.

Answer (score 2):

Simple solution is to use the pause symbol from the Webdings font, no elements, transforms required

Example:

```
  <Button FontFamily="Webdings" FontSize="20" Content=";" />
```

[image]